# Store instances into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, instances

I am working on a project where I have a bunch of buttons, mostly split into two groups and I would like to work with these groups through an array. Each button is an instance of `class Button extends JButton` and each instance has its own value (`this.value = ".."`)

The problem is that it seems like array is being filled with previously mentioned instances, but when I try to reach them, it acts like array is filled with nulls.

```
Button but1, but2, but3;
Button[] buttonNumbers = {but1, but2, but3};

System.out.println(buttonNumbers.length);     // returns 3, so it acts like array IS filled
System.out.println(but1.value);               // prints whatever the value is
System.out.println(buttonNumbers[0].value);    // throws error, element acts like null
```

Could someone help me out, where is the problem or what am I missing ?
Thank you for every tip or answer!

Comment: In your example, there are no `Button` instances. You have to call a constructor of class `Button` to create an instance.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem like you're initializing each `Button`!  You need to call its constructor for each `Button` with whatever parameters you defined:

```
Button but1 = new Button(), but2 = new Button(), but3 = new Button();
Button[] buttonNumbers = {but1, but2, but3};

System.out.println(buttonNumbers.length);     // returns 3, so it acts like array IS filled
System.out.println(but1.value);               // prints whatever the value is
System.out.println(buttonNumbers[0].value);
```

Comment: I have called all constructors after i filled the array, can be this the problem ? 
I thought that if i declare these buttons before creating them, i can fill an array with them, have i been mistaken?

Comment: Yes, they must be called before filling the array!  You can fill the array with uninitialized variables (like you already did), but then it's just an array of `null`s.

Comment: So just to be clear, if i fill an array with only declared variables, java knows how much memory it needs, but i can't access them until i initialize them? Otherwise i am working only with allocated memory?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You can access any element in the array (since the array was initialized), but every element in the array is `null` since they have't been initialized with `new Button()` before that point.

Comment: I understand now what i have done wrong. Code now works and i understand why. Thank you!